# How to know a file exists in the Desktop using Python on Mac OS?

Tags: python, macos

I would like to see whether a file is on the desktop in Mac OS and I write the code:

```
if path.exists('~/Desktop/AZDif.png'):
    print 'Yes'
else:
    print 'No, the file is not there'
```

I see the file is not in the Desktop while it was actually there. How to write the code properly ?

Comment: Does this link help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-to-check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python

Comment: That was not for Mac OS, but, generally yes.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to include the solution, you can write it as an answer.

Comment: Okay, I put it as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution I find for Mac OS using Python:

```
if path.exists(path.expanduser('~/Desktop/AZDif.png')):
    print 'Yes'
```

There should also be a way to use absolute path as well. I will check and improve the answer.